# Refresh page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage, in that page I have a button. How can I refresh the page when clicking on that button?

Comment: You have to provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using an

```
<asp:button />
```

tag?

If so the page should refresh when the button is clicked by default.

Comment: ya mr.paul i am using asp button

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Reload" onclick="window.location.reload(true);" />
```

However, if the page is created from a postback, you would need to use an `asp:Button` control instead, and let another postback refresh the page. You also have to make sure that the correct code is executed in the code behind to recreate the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
   <input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit Information Now" />
</form>
```

SUBMIT is a TYPE attribute value to the INPUT element for FORMs. It specifies a button that, when activated, submits the information entered to a processing script. If there are multiple SUBMIT buttons in a form, only the one activated should be sent to the form processing script.

Answer (score 0):

When you press button your page must refresh, only not refresh that controls which are in AJAX Update Panel